# Finite String Array in Delphi Prism

Tags: arrays, string, character, delphi-prism

I can't seem to find answer anywhere on how to create a string array with finite numbers of characters.

For instance, in Delphi you can declare a string array variable with x number of characters like so.

```
var TmpStr:string[10];
```

How do you do the same in Delphi Prism? or Can you even do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the Array types in (Delphi) Prism / the Oxygene language are explained here: http://prismwiki.embarcadero.com/en/Array_Types

Comment: @ Sebastian, I was on this website up and down. That website is very tricky to navigate. If you loose your way, you have to start all over again. Thanks.